# Unable to view the runtime when creating the project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have installed .Net Core SDK (SDK 3.1.302) and Hosting Bundle (dotnet-hosting-3.1.6-win.exe) from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1
When I create a new empty project, and while selecting the template

1. When I select the framework .Net Framework, it correctly shows the template where-in I can select .Net Core Runtime version of .Net Core 3.1
   [image: Shows asp.net core runtime 3.1]
2. But when I select the framework .Net Framework, it does not show the template where-in I can select .Net Core Runtime version of .Net Core 3.1
   [image: Does Not show asp.net core runtime 3.1]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any update? Does my reply has helped you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [break changes document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/2.2-3.1#target-framework-net-framework-support-dropped) from asp.net core 2.1 to 3.0.

> Target framework: .NET Framework support dropped
> Starting with ASP.NET Core 3.0, .NET Framework is an unsupported target framework.

> NET Framework 4.8 is the last major version of .NET Framework. New ASP.NET Core apps should be built on .NET Core. Starting with the .NET Core 3.0 release, you can think of ASP.NET Core 3.0 as being part of .NET Core.

> Customers using ASP.NET Core with .NET Framework can continue in a fully supported fashion using the 2.1 LTS release. Support and servicing for 2.1 continues until at least August 21, 2021. This date is three years after declaration of the LTS release per the .NET Support Policy. Support for ASP.NET Core 2.1 packages on .NET Framework will extend indefinitely, similar to the servicing policy for other package-based ASP.NET frameworks.

So you couldn't create .net frmwork asp.net core application after 2.2.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I was really struggling to find the answer.

Comment: If you feel my answer has helped you, please mark it as answer. So that other folks could find the answer more easily.